# Basic graph theory matching question -- I don't understand the answer to this

Tags: combinatorics

We generalize the idea of matching in Example 1 to arbitrary graphs by defining
a matching to be a pairing off of adjacent vertices in a graph. For example, one
possible matching in Figure 1.1 is a-b, c-d. For Figure 1.2, is there matching?  If not, explain why.

Figure 1.1

[image]

Figure 1.2

[image]

The answer in the book says this:

a,c,e collectively must be matched with just b and e.

I am assuming the answer means no, there is no match.  But, the answer doesn't make sense to me.  If a match is a pairing off of adjacent vertices, then a-b and d-e must be adjacent vertices in some pair.  I'm not sure if vertices can be used again in a match, but if not, then vertex c makes it impossible for either a-b or d-e to be used in a match with c.  I'm not sure what to make of the answer or question.  I'm trying to find a solutions manual, but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You cannot reuse the vertices otherwise it would be trivial. If there was a matching, then $a,b$ and $d,e$ would have to be pairs (no other choice), which would leave $c$ isolated.

Comment: It's clear why there is no matching, but I agree that the stated answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the book has a typo and it should say $a$, $c$, and $e$ must be matched with $b$ and $d$.

Your logic is correct and emulates what the book is trying to say which is that there can be no perfect matching (I'll define this in a second) because it is impossible to find a match for $c$ since $b$ and $d$ are already taken by $a$ and $e$ respectively.

A matching cannot reuse vertices.

Now, your book is a little bit misleading in that it seems to be using the term 'matching' to refer to a 'perfect matching'. A matching is properly defined as set of edges without common vertices, while a perfect matching is a matching such that every vertex in the graph is adjacent to some edge in the matching.

In the second example, a valid matching would be $\{(b,h),(c,d)\}$ where $(x,y)$ refers to the edge between vertices $x$ and $y$. The empty set would even be a valid matching. So in answer to the question, there certainly exist matchings in the the second example, but there are not any perfect matchings.

To learn more, see the [Wikipedia page on matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Ah, ok.  So, in a graph with an odd number of vertices, there can not exist a perfect matching, but a matching can exist.  And, I'm inclined to believe the book has an error.  Thanks for the response!